# Filtered search with multiple fields using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code is what I have in my Index.cs

```
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By:</b>
    @Html.TextBox("progcd") <text>PROGCD</text>
    @Html.TextBox("docrecdt") <text>DOCRECDT</text>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
</p>
```

And in my home controller is

```
   public ActionResult Index(string progcd, string docrecdt)
        {

            if (docrecdt == "docrecdt")
            {
                return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt).ToList());
            }         
            else if (progcd == "progcd")
            {
                return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt && x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
            }           
        }       
    }
```

The only view that returns is the last one where both fields must match. If I only put one field which I'm attempting to satisfy either the "if" or "else if" statement, it does not function. How can I adjust my code so that it will function for all three statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your conditions using a `||` condition like

```
        if (docrecdt.ToLower() == "docrecdt" || progcd.ToLower() == "progcd")
        {
            return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt || x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
        }         
        else
        {
            return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt && x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code still does not work.. The problem where the return View only shows when both fields are filled in is still there. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @ayton, in that case your model binder is not able to bind the action method parameter itself and so it's going to else block.

Comment: Also, case sensitivity could be an issue here. Check edit now and see.

Comment: When I comment everything out except for 
return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt || x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
this part works and returns the individual fields but when I uncomment and include the if and else statement then it only works when both fields are completed